# How can I read array from JSON with jagged array

Tags: arrays, json

I am using jsonutility in Unity3d(c#). Below code contains a jagged array.

How can I deserialize the jagged array, in order to get the value inside the array?

```
{
  "location": [
    [
      {
        "locationId": 2362,
        "locationName": "Shackleford Crossing 554",
        "latitude": 34.731603,
        "longitude": -92.3955491,
        "easternOffset": 0
      },
      {
        "locationId": 2030,
        "locationName": "MISHAWAKA 3301",
        "latitude": 41.6999082,
        "longitude": -86.1882506,
        "easternOffset": 0
      }
    ]
  ],
  "product": [
    [
      {
        "id": 778,
        "name": "Leinenkugel Summer Shandy",
        "style": "Ale"
      },
      {
        "id": 8771,
        "name": "Leinenkugel Harvest Patch Shandy",
        "style": "Ale"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity)

Comment: What is a jagged Array?

Comment: Jagged array is array of arrays , you can find out more about it here : 
  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/jagged-arrays-in-C-Sharp-net/